# custom column width with multicols using xtab package

Tags: tables

How to customize the width of a particular column in table created using `xtab`? In my case I have the following `xtab` specification in my document:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{xtab}
\usepackage{a4pdf}
\begin{document}


\topcaption{Review} \label{tab:table5.1}
\tablefirsthead{\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Overview}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Remarks}} & 
 \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Method/s}} \\ \hline }
\tablehead{\multicolumn{2}{c}%
{{\captionsize\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} --
continued from previous page}} \\
\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Overview}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Remarks}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Method/s}} \\ \hline }
\tablelasthead{\multicolumn{2}{c}%
{{\captionsize\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} --
concluded from previous page}} \\
\hline \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Overview}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Remarks}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Method/s}} \\ \hline }
\tabletail{\hline \multicolumn{2}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline}
\tablelasttail{\hline \hline}
\begin{center}
\begin{xtabular}{|p{0.45\textwidth}|p{0.45\textwidth}|p{0.05\textwidth}|}
Column1 & Column2 & Column3 \\
\end{xtabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

What I want is the first two columns to have the same width, and the last column to have minimal width, using `\textwidth`. I am using a4 page settings. Kindly advise. The problem I face is that I cannot specify custom widths to each column using `p{\textwidth}`. I can only specify a uniform width for all the three columns.

Comment: Could you make your document so that it is compilable? Note that the linked post references the `multicol` package, while your approach using a tabular-like structure is completely different.

Comment: @Werner ok, I will edit my previous post.

Comment: Your code still doesn't compile...

Comment: @Werner I guess I have not specified the width for the column using |p|. It should compile if I were to edit that. I had not specified that since I was not sure how \columnsep would change the width then. That was where I had the beginning of my confusion. I will edit the question again.

Comment: No. A minimal example should *start* with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. Does your do this? We want to copy-and-paste-and-compile the code and see exactly what the problem is. Surely the `p`-columns are a problem, but apart from that, set things up so that *that* is the *only* problem.

Comment: @Werner I have edited the code and it compiles for me, only that I do not get the custom width as I want.